# Problem with an image

Tags: graphics, captions

I have a template for my project and I don't know very much about LaTeX.
It puts that for putting an image is:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
% dummy figure replacement 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\rule{.5\textwidth}{.5\textwidth} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{fig:example}A figure}
\end{figure}
```

but I think that in this text is missing a command to insert the image like this: `\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{mifigure}` but if I put that, it does´t work.

also if I put `\includegraphics` without `width=0.7\textwidth`, the image appear too big to the side of the document.

(my image is inside a folder and it is `.png`)

Now I have another problem related to this.

In main.tex

```
\documentclass{MScthesisITEM}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
```

In example `chapter4.tex`

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
% dummy figure replacement 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\rule{.5\textwidth}{.5\textwidth} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{fig:example}A figure}
\end{figure}
```

This shows a black image in the center of the document.

In my chapter.tex

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
% dummy figure replacement 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\rule{.5\textwidth}{.5\textwidth} \\
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{circuitpacket}
\end{tabular}

\caption{ Explanation...}
\label{fig:comparison_circuit}
\end{figure}
```

I obtained the black image and my image after the black image. How can I erase the black image?

Comment: Hello Juan, welcome to the community. First, it is a good idea that you include on your code the `documentclass` and additional packages you're using... because the result depend on these things... Make sure you've included the package `graphicx`. Second, I'm not sure it is customary to insert the `\label` on the `\caption` argument (although it depends on the `class` you're using. Third, there's an option (intead of `width`, you can use `\includegraphics[scale=.2]{myfigure}`

Comment: If you have any problem after trying my answer, please drop some comments.

Comment: when I put the package that you mention I have an error, so I updated the question with more info.
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: `\rule{<width>}{<height>}` creates a black box, so the line
`\rule{.5\textwidth}{.5\textwidth} \\` adds a square black box.

Comment: If you want to include standard figures more easily check out the `easyfig` package.

Answer (score 3):

If your images are in the same directory in which the input file exist, the following code should work. Please make a try by replacing `example-image-a` with `your-image-filename`. And make sure you compile with `pdflatex` rather than `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Hello Universe}
\label{fig:HelloUniverse}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But if your images are in a sub directory `subdir1`, `subdir2`, etc, for example, then you need to specify the graphics path as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{subdir1/}{subdir2/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Hello Universe}
\label{fig:HelloUniverse}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```